# Visual Web Developer and Crystal Reports 11

Tags: crystal-reports, vwdexpress

How Do I add a Crystal Report to my web project which I created using Visual Web Developer?

As searching for any topic related to the question, most sites I have seen takes note that Visual Studio already has the Crystal Reports built in.

I wonder for those who only have VWD, how do we utilize Crystal Reports 11 then?

And also, what would be the assemblies that I need to be deploying to the server?

Would I be deploying the assemblies only or do I need to install Crystal Reports 11 to my web server as well?

Appreciate any response on this.

Thanks.

Comment: I found out that I would have to add some assemblies to the GAC of the IIS server where I plan to deploy the application. Assemblies related to the Crystal Report.  For the application itself, I need to add references to those assemblies and declare them in the web config of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add some assemblies to the GAC of the IIS server where I plan to deploy the application. Assemblies related to the Crystal Report. For the application itself, I need to add references to those assemblies and declare them in the web config of the application